# haml file seems causing HTTP ERROR 500 ruby on rails6 at Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, haml

I'm upgrading ruby, rails and the other gems of an old application built on ruby2 running on Heroku.
I made it to deploy to Heroku but HTTP ERROR 500 occurs.

the error log is this below

```
 ActionView::Template::Error (login.js):
    40:   = image_tag "app_logo.png", id: "app_logo", alt: "app"
    41: 
    42: %span#dest
    43:   = javascript_include_tag "login"
app/views/sessions/_login.html.haml:43
app/views/sessions/login.html.haml:1
```

When I commented out this part `= javascript_include_tag "login"`
no error is emitted but also nothing appeared on the application page.

If anyone have any idea to solve it share with me please.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your HAML code can be translated like this :

```
%span#dest
   = javascript_include_tag "login"
```

```html
<span id="dest">
   <script src="/assets/login.js"></script>
</span>
```

The error means that your application failed to load the `/assets/login.js`.

You should look there what have messed up.

Comment: thank you. I looked there and there is `assets\javascripts\login.js.coffee`. is the coffee file causing the problem?